# Duplicate settings of master blog to slave blogs in WP multi-site installation

Tags: plugins, multisite, options

Is there any smart way to set a site (blog) as a master, which settings are replicated to the rest of the sites in the network?

There are plugins like this one: [YD Network-wide WPML](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yd-network-wide-wpml/) that attempt to accomplish this, but they don't support all settings.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what types of "settings" you're referring to?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options I'm aware of, and neither are free:

http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/new-blog-template

http://wpebooks.com/replicator/

I haven't actually tried either of them yet, so can't recommend one over the other.

Comment: replicator works fine for me - just create a site with all pages / plugin settings / menu's / ... - and everything is perfectly copied to the new site. well worth it's 35$.

Answer (score 1):

there is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/default-blog-options/ too.. but its not working for custom post type or taxonomies..

Answer (score 0):

With this plugin it's possible to duplicate everything from a site of the network to a new one.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-cloned-sites-for-wpmu-batch/

I use it like this:

- configure one or more template sites (settings, plugins, theme, menus, widgets)
- archive them
- when a new site is needed, activate the template and clone
- archive template

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option to consider: 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blog-copier/